# Is there any framework to verify the DDL script (CREATE and ALTER) generated by Liquibase (in offline mode) using the ORM xml?

Tags: hibernate, orm, liquibase

I am successful in generating the `DDL` script for my `jpa entity` using `Liquibase` (in offline mode and I am only generating it and not applying it to any database).

I have my `hibernate` `orm.xml` for my jpa entity which has the information about my entity attributes and it's types and also the information about the constraints that I need.

With these 2 things in my hand ie

1. Sql ddl script.
2. Orm mapping xml

Is there any framework or approach with which I can test my generated ddl script?

Can someone put light on this?